# In LibreOffice Calc, how would I convert a sheet containing survey responses into a two dimensional grid?

Tags: sql-server, libreoffice

For instance, if I have this data:

```
Name    Question                            Answer
Alice   What is your favorite color?        blue
Alice   What is your favorite video game?   Minecraft
Alice   What is your favorite number?       42
Bob     What is your favorite color?        red
Bob     What is your favorite video game?   Team Fortress 2
Bob     What is your favorite number?       7
Charlie What is your favorite color?        green
Charlie What is your favorite video game?   Candy Crush
Charlie What is your favorite number?       -1
```

I want it to be formatted like so:

```
Name    What is your favorite color?    What is your favorite video game?   What is your favorite number?
Alice   blue                            Minecraft                           42
Bob     red                             Team Fortress 2                     7
Charlie green                           Candy Crush                         -1
```

Is there any way to do this in LibreOffice Calc? (Or in SQL Server; that's where I'm getting the data from.)

Comment: In Sql Server use `PIVOT`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I read about SQL `PIVOT` but it looks like it only works with a hardcoded list of values? I can't dynamically generate the column headers from my data, can I?

Comment: Are there always the same number of rows per name in the source data?

Comment: I think so; a cursory glance at the data seems to show that each person has the same list of questions associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *In the original question the poster included using Excel as a possible solution. He has since edited his question to clarify that he only wanted a LibreOffice or SQL solution. But I will leave this answer in case Excel users stumble upon this question in the future*

In Excel you can use `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010 and later).

- Pivot on the `Question` column
- Select `Answers` for the `Values` column
- Under `Advanced Options` select `Don't aggregate`

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Question", type text}, {"Answer", type any}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Question]), "Question", "Answer")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

**Source Data**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that looks really cool, but in LibreOffice Calc, which I'm using, I don't see any option to disable aggregation, so I'm stuck with a sum of the survey answers, which doesn't really mean anything and the cells come up blank...

Comment: @ekolis I suggest you edit your question, in which you asked for a ***"way to do this in Excel or LibreOffice Calc?"*** to clarify that you are only interested in methods that will work in LibreOffice Calc.